# jPlayer doesn't work (I suppose because of old flash-plugin)

Tags: flash, jplayer

I have insert jPlayer (http://www.jplayer.org/) into my site (http://en.lyrsense.com/) and I've got a lot of feedback that it deosn't work. I suppose that it's because of old version of flash-plugin, but no one browser show block whith class .jp-no-solution. I've checked all browsers at home and at work — everywhere it works. But there are too many feedbacks that jplayer doesn't play music.

I'm sorry for my english, I'm from Russia.

Very thankfull,
Rodion

Comment: did you discover why your player was not working for some users?

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin is working well without any problem. You can show `.jp-no-solution` with jQuery too. I couldn't get the question well but I think you are trying to show `.jp-no-solution`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.jp-no-solution').css("display","block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jPlayer works fine for me in IE7, IE8 and Chrome..

jPlayer requires Flash version 10.3 at the minimum to work, you will need to ask your users with playback issues to upgrade Flash!

Here is a link to a discussion on this subject:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jplayer/GmWrzIf7dDE/discussion