# Jplayer with XML not working

Tags: javascript, html, xml, jplayer

I am trying to get Jplayer to work using an XML doc so my customer can easily update the playlist. I was able to get it working without issues when I code the songs into the JS. My current code is:

```
<div class="body-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8" id="overlay-box">
            <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
              <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
                <div class="jp-type-single">
                  <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                    <ul class="jp-controls">
                      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="jp-progress">
                      <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                      <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="jp-playlist">
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                  <div class="jp-no-solution">
                    <p>Update Required
                    <br />
                    To play the media you will need to update your browser to a newer version.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

And then my JS code is:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
// Get the Playlist from the xml file
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: "./mp3/playlist.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('track').each(function(){
                var self = $(this),
                     mytitle = self.find('title').text(),
                     myartist = self.find('artist').text(),
                     mymp3 = self.find('mp3').text(),
                     playlist = JSON.stringify({ title: mytitle, artist : myartist, mp3 : mymp3 }),// Convert the XML nodes into JSON formatted strings
                     playlistObject = $.parseJSON(playlist); // Convert the JSON formatted strings into JSON objects and add to playlist

                myPlaylist.add(playlistObject);
        });
    }
});

    // Jplayer Playlist instance
    var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "jp_container_1"
    }, [ 
            // Playlist is created when the page loads via ajax
        ], 
    {
        playlistOptions: {
          autoPlay: false, // self explanatory
          loopOnPrevious: false, //  If loop is active, the playlist will loop back to the end when executing previous()
          shuffleOnLoop: true, //  If loop and shuffle are active, the playlist will shuffle when executing next() on the last item
          enableRemoveControls: false, // Adds an x that allows user to remove songs from playlist
          displayTime: 0, // how fast the playlist transitions on page load
          addTime: 'fast', // transition time when adding a song
          removeTime: 'fast', // transition time when removing a song
          shuffleTime: 'slow' // transition time when shuffling playlist
        },
        supplied: "mp3", // add the file format extension you will be streaming
        wmode: "window"

    });
});


</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prettify-jPlayer.js"></script>
```

My XML file is:

```
<playlist>
    <track>
        <title>Waving Not Drowning</title>
        <artist>Orbital</artist>
        <mp3>http://www.beyondhyper.com/mp3/Orbital-The Altogether-WavingNotDrowning.mp3</mp3>
    </track>
    <track>
        <title>Crazy People</title>
        <artist>3 Monkeys</artist>
        <mp3>http://www.beyondhyper.com/mp3/3Monkeys-CrazyPeople.mp3</mp3>
    </track>
    <track>
        <title>Voices</title>
        <artist>Bedrock</artist>
        <mp3>http://www.beyondhyper.com/mp3/Bedrock- Voices.mp3</mp3>
    </track>
    <track>
        <title>Timeless</title>
        <artist>Transa</artist>
        <mp3>http://www.beyondhyper.com/mp3/Transa-Timeless.mp3</mp3>
    </track>
</playlist>
```

No matter what I do, I only see the 'no solution' tag. If anyone has any idea as to what I am missing please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible causes:

- `jp-no-solution` is shown if HTML5 is not available and Flash is not installed
- `jp-no-solution` is shown if Flash is installed but Flash is outdated
- `jp-no-solution` is shown if JavaScript is disabled

**References**

- [jplayer Release Notes](http://www.jplayer.org/2.6.0/release-notes/)
- [jPlayer doesn't work (I suppose because of old flash-plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504181/1113772)